# distance among points in a linestring using args

Tags: python, line, distance, points, args

in the code bellow points need be arranged according to the values of x and then calculate the distance not manually as I did below but automatically with unknown number of points

```
class line(Point):

    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.n = [Point(p[0], p[1]) for p in args]
        # here the points need be arranged
        # according to the values of x 
        # and then calculate the distance not manually
        # as I did below but automatically 
        # with an unknown number of points 
        print(self.n)
```

Comment: Where is the manual distance calculation?

Comment: What is the `Point` class and how is it defined?

Comment: Have a look at [Shapely](http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html#linestrings) to calculate the length of line strings automatically.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.... also dont expect people here to write code for you, you should come with errors and problems in your code. What have you tried so far?